# Run Django South migrations on in-memory objects

Tags: python, django, orm, django-south

I have an export file which contains a bunch of serialised Django models. I use this to implement an import/export feature for my DB.

The problem is, some of my customers have upgraded their system, including running several South migrations, and their export file is now out-of-date.

One solution I'm considering is to import the serialised objects, upgrade them in some way using South (since the full migration history is present in the DB), then write them in their upgraded form.

**Question**

Is there any way to do what I'm describing using South? A simple way to run South migrations on "in-memory objects" in some way could also work.

Also, if anyone has other suggestions for dealing with this issue, I'm open to hear them.

Thanks!

Comment: South does not work with data, it works with the _database schema_. You're going to need to create a new database with the schema that is expected by your export file, import your data there, and use South to migrate the schema to your latest migration, then you can export it again and reimport in your live database. That won't happen "in memory" without an actual database.

Comment: @lanzz: Yeah that's what I'm afraid of. I was hoping there would be some trick I could use, although after a lot of searching it's looking like there isn't an easy way to do this.